# hdf5 files containing matrix N x M as input for machine learning with keras

Tags: python, matrix, machine-learning, keras

I need help/opinion regarding the input for doing machine learning.

I have one hdf5 file

```
combined.h5
```

that contains several dataset where each dataset contains matrix of 4 X 125 (4 row and 125 column)

I have been searching on how to input the hdf5 file containing matrix as input for machine learning but did not found any answer/example that good enough for me as reference . Below is my modified script

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

seed = 7
np.random.seed(seed)

dataset = h5py.File('combined.h5', 'r') #has 5 dataset

X = dataset #input
Y = ["A","CFL","SS","G","FF"] #output

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(125, input_dim=125, init='normal', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(5, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)

scores = model.evaluate(X, Y)

print("%s: %.2f%%" % (model.metrics_names[1], scores[1]*100))
```

I ran this script and got error like below

```
TypeError: Error when checking model input: data should be a Numpy array, or list/dict of Numpy arrays. Found: <HDF5 file "combined.h5" (mode r)>...
```

My question is how to load the hdf5 files containing datasets in form of matrix as input data for machine learning?

*Additional question, I want to link the output for each dataset. For example, dataset 1 has output data of "A", dataset 2 has output data of "CFL" and so on...
Is there any proper way to do this or is it enough with what I wrote in the script?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be for every named dataset:

```
X = dataset['dataset_name'][:] #input
```

to find out the names of the dataset you can use the following script:

```
for key in dataset.keys():
    print key
```

Here you take the full dataset out of the file. If you do not slice the dataset you only get a pointer to the h5py dataset object. With the slice operator you extract the numpy array. (http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/high/dataset.html#reading-writing-data)

You just have to imagine your hdf5 file to be like a folder structure you have to traverse the folder structure to get to your data. Then you can use slicing to load the data.

Comment: do I need to replace `dataset_name` with the name of the dataset in the hdf5 file? can you elaborate more on this? for example if I have datasets with name `AA`, `BB`, do I need to write like this --> `X = dataset['AA'][:]` for dataset `AA` and `X = dataset['BB'][:]` for dataset `BB` each? or is it `X = dataset['dataset_name'][:]` enough to address all the dataset in the hdf5 file?

Comment: Dataset_name is a placeholder for an actual dataset name like AA.